# An Inequality $(1-p)^{2}p^{m}\leq1-p-p^{m}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

In [1, pp.~342], the authors use the inequality
\begin{equation}
(1-p)^{2}p^{m}\leq1-p-p^{m},
\end{equation}
where $p\in[0,1)$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy $p+\frac{3}{2}p^{m}\leq1$.

I **cannot** see easily that this inequality holds.

When $m=1$, the inequality becomes $(1-p)^{2}p\leq1-2p$ and the condition becomes $p\leq\frac{2}{5}$. In this case, inequality holds for $p\leq0.43016$. For greater values of $m$, I do **not** see a simple proof.

However, with some calculus, I think it is possible to prove this inequality but I would like to know if it is possible to give a simple proof for it.

**References**.
[1] X.H. Tang, X.F. Zou, Asymptotic Stability of a Neutral Differential Equations, *Proc. Edinb. Math. Soc.* (2) 45 (2002), no. 2, 333--347.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple proof.

We can rewrite the equation $p + \frac{3}{2}p^m\leq 1$ as
$$
0\geq 3p^m+2p-2=3p^m+3p-3-p+1=3(p^m+p-1)-(p-1),
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
1-p-p^m \geq (1-p)/3.
$$
Our goal is to prove $1-p-p^m \geq (1-p)^2p^m$ so let's show that $(1-p)/3 \geq (1-p)^2p^m$, which in it's own turn is equivalent to $(1-p)p^m\leq 1/3$. Since $p\in[0,1)$ we have
$$
(1-p)p^m \leq (1-p)p \leq \frac{1}{4} \leq 1/3,
$$
which finishes the proof.

Comment: The final inequality is something I am familiar with from the oscillation theory. At that point, we have $(1-p)p^{m}\leq\frac{m^{m}}{(m+1)^{m+1}}\leq\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0 \le p < 1/3$ then
$$
 (1-p)^2p^m + p^m \le 2p^m < 2 p < 1-p \, ,
$$
and if $1/3 \le p < 1$ then, using $p^m \le \frac 23 (1-p)$,
$$
 (1-p)^2p^m + p^m \le (\frac 49+1) \frac 23 (1-p) = \frac{26}{27}(1-p) < 1-p \, .
$$

Comment: The final inequality can also be written as follows.
$[(1-p)p^{m}](1-p)+p^{m}\leq\frac{m^{m}}{(m+1)^{m+1}}(1-p)+\frac{2}{3}(1-p)
=\bigl(\frac{m^{m}}{(m+1)^{m+1}}+\frac{2}{3}\bigr)(1-p)\leq\big(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2}{3}\bigr)(1-p)=\frac{11}{12}(1-p)<1-p.$